# Reconnect with XMPP when user is getting error or disconnect from XMPP

Tags: ios, xmpp

I have implemented a chatting application with the help of `XMPP` framework. But I am getting an error as shown :

```
xmpp did receive error:-
Printing description of error:
<stream:error xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><conflict xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams"></conflict><text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams" lang="">Replaced by new connection</text></stream>
```

Need some guidance on what could be causing this error and how to reconnect using `XMPP`.

Thanks.

Comment: When you getting this error

Comment: You have been disconnected by the server because another client connected to your account with the same resource as yours. The 'resource' is a unique identifier for each session connected to the account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use XMPPReconnect class..

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) XMPPReconnect *xmppReconnect;

self.xmppReconnect = [[XMPPReconnect alloc] init];
[self.xmppReconnect activate:self.xmppStream];
[self.xmppReconnect addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

And implement 'XMPPReconnect' delegate methods

```
- (void)xmppReconnect:(XMPPReconnect *)sender didDetectAccidentalDisconnect:(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags)connectionFlags
{
    NSLog(@"didDetectAccidentalDisconnect:%u",connectionFlags);
}
- (BOOL)xmppReconnect:(XMPPReconnect *)sender shouldAttemptAutoReconnect:(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags)reachabilityFlags
{
    NSLog(@"shouldAttemptAutoReconnect:%u",reachabilityFlags);
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe XMPPReconnect stops working when the client receives this error from the server. Check XMPPReconnect.m. You will see in the delegate functions that when this error is received, the variable shouldReconnect is set to NO, which means there will be no further reconnection attempt.

The explanation is that "normally" this error is received when another client connects using the same resource, therefore XMPPReconnect is disabled to avoid an endless cycle of reconnections and disconnections between the two different clients and the server.

However, I noticed that you sometimes get this error even though only one client is connected. So if you are sure that no two different clients will ever attempt to connect to the server simultaneously, I would suggest commenting the line setting shouldReconnect to NO, thus allowing XMPPFramework to consider it an ordinary disconnection.